# Using phpmailer in the right syntax

Tags: phpmailer

When im using the phpmailer with this code: `$mail = new phpmailer();` should i give a true paramteret for it, or its not important?

I mean: `$mail = new phpmailer(true);`

whether it is important, to put the email sending in a try block, and in a catch block to get the errors?

Thanks!

**Update, my code, what i use:**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try
    {
        $mail->From = $site_config['k_contact_email'];
        $mail->FromName = $site_config['k_webshop_nev'];
        $to = $user_email;
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->AddAddress($user_email);
        $mail->Subject = "Regisztráció aktiválása";
        $mail->AltBody = "Hogy az üzenetet megtekintse, kérjük, kapcsoljon át HTML nézetre.";
        $mail->WordWrap = 80;
        $mail->loadtemplate("upd_email/regisztracio.html");
        $mail->assign('title','Regisztráció aktiválása');

        // Személyes adatok
        $mail->assign('user_nev', $user_vnev .' '. $user_knev );
        $mail->assign('aktivation_link', "".$host."?activation=".$user_aktivation."");
        $mail->assign('domain_name', $host);
        $mail->assign('domain_address', $host);
        $mail->assign('akt_email_text', $site_config['k_email_akt_text']);
        $mail->MsgHTML($mail->message);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Send();
        header("Location:".$host."/uzenet/uj-regisztracio");
    }
    catch (phpmailerException $e) {echo $e->errorMessage(); } 
    catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); }
```

Comment: i think $mail = new PHPMailer; this is enough by default

Comment: But without the true parameter, sometimes, i didnt get the email.

Comment: If you didn't get the e-mil you'd need to do so some proper error-handlings, such as looking at the exception (if any) and/or looking at the return codes of the functions you called. Given that the problem is on your side and it isn't any server limiting you.

Comment: I writed the code in my first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) never hurt anyone. In the main example on that page they use phpmailer without exceptions (and without true in the constructor).

If you however look at the constructor definition in the [API documentation](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method___construct) then you can see that passing true will make sure the class will (re)throw internal errors. If true is not set in the constructor it will likey catch all internal errors and return the through an error code.

So if you pass true in the constructor, you will need to catch exceptions and handle them. If you don't pass true then an `if(!$mail->send()){}` will be likely be sufficient.

Comment: Exactly right, thanks for paying attention! It generally doesn't make that big a difference, because many things are not used/checked until you call `send()`.

Comment: I think, i will use it with the true parameter, and try catch block. Maybe, this is the better solution.